# In Programs and Features Columns displayed are customized for music

Tags: windows-10, add-and-remove-programs

When I view Programs and Features in details mode the details are customized for music (I have seen this in other system level displays).

In Programs and Features I tried selecting Tools | Folder Options from the menu. Then click the Restore Defaults button. This did not change the columns being displayed.

I have googled for this issue but found nothing. Can anyone help me resolve this?

**About my Laptop:**

System Model:
Hewlett-Packard HP ENVY TS 17 Notebook PC

Operating System:
Windows 10 Professional (x64) Version 2009 (build 19045.3930)

Windows Specs:
Version 22H2
OS Build 19045.3930

Processor:
2.40 gigahertz Intel Core i7-4700MQ,
64 kilobyte primary memory cache,
64-bit ready,
Multi-core (4 total),
Hyper-threaded (8 total)

[image: Programs and Features window image]

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the Windows OS has been damaged. As shown below, columns such as *Album* and *Genre* should not be available in that view. [To select columns, either choose *View | Choose details...* or right-click the column header.]

[image: Programs and Features columns]

*Explorer* and *Programs and Features* are integrated deeply into Windows, so that the first thing to try is repairing Windows.

- Use [DISM and SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) for in-place repair.
- If that does not fix the issue, [try reinstalling from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), but keeping files.
- Finally, if those comparatively simpler repairs are not  sufficient, the user profile might be damaged. You might need to [repair the profile or create a new profile](https://windowsreport.com/corrupt-user-profile-windows-10/) and transfer as much of the current to the new as possible. Frankly, this is a pain, and can lead to issues, so is left for last.

Comment: Thank you DrMoishe Pippik.

I tried DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth followed by sfc /scannow. I immediately opened Programs and Features and the detail columns were correct. I closed the window and came back about 20 minutes later and the music columns reappeared. Next I ran DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth followed by sfc /scannow again then re-booted. After the boot I opened Programs and Features and the correct columns were displayed (Name, Date Modified, Type, Size).

Was a re-boot necessary for this fix to stick?

Comment: You may be seeing different views depending on the shell namespace path. `Control Panel\Prograqms\Programs and Features` and `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` can have different views saved.

Comment: " I immediately opened Programs and Features and the detail columns were correct. I closed the window and came back about 20 minutes later and the music columns reappeared." You've provided useful information. Now use Task Manager, Details tab, to see if there is some extra process, *not* part of Windows, running that could make that change. Also use Microsoft/Sysinternals Autoruns, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns, to check what processes start up on their own. Have you installed a music indexing, app, for example?

Comment: Your comment on shell namespace was correct (should have figured this out myself since I was a .net programmer quite a few years ago). I have 3 ways to open Programs and Features (Control Panel, God Mode, my own shortcut). 1 Had the correct columns after the DISM & Scannow but the other 2 were both different. I open Programs and Features with the proper column display then selected Tools | Folder Options | View Tab and clicked on Apply to Folders button. Now all 3 ways to view  Programs and Features look the same. BTW: I downloaded Autoruns and am in love with what I can see\do with this app.

Comment: I did not recently install a new Music App. However a few weeks ago my PC flipped out and many of the Desktop Icons rearranged themselves right in front of my eves. I immediately run a scan for viruses and malware using Norton360 (nothing was found).

Answer (score 1):

It's not major damage! It's just the wromg view template.

On the menu bar in **Programs and Feartures**, choose:

- `Tools` ->`Folder Options...` -> `View` tab -> `Reset Folders`

[image]

Comment: Sorry I did not have a chance to try your suggestion. The DISM.exe and sfc /scannow found the following 6 issues after which the columns in Programs and Features were displaying correctly. But not sure how these issues and my problem are related.

In ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Definition Updates\Default\\ found: MpAsBase.vdm, MpAsDlta.vdm, MpAvBase.vdm, MpAvDlta.vdm,MpEngine.dll from store & 

AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\\OneDrive.lnk from store.

Glad I ran DISM & scannow to find these issues but would have liked to have tried your suggestion first.

Comment: @mikemich: No worries -- you may get a chance someday... :) The same "trick" works to restore the custom grouping in Quick Access and the custom columns in Network, Contacts, and probably a few others I can't think of right now... :D

Comment: I did in fact have a grouping issue with God Mode and Quick Access. Your approach fixed those for me, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: With all of these recent issues I have been experiencing with File Explorer I am considering running winfilefolder.DiagCab. I am going to research this more before I take the leap and plan on cloning my drive first...just in case.

Comment: If it's all or mostly view-related, you might have maxed out saved views. Copy & paste this PowerShell snippet to check. If you've hit 5000, you've maxed out: `(gp 'HKcu:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU').Nodeslots.Count`  # If you have, you need to delete the `BagMRU` and `Bags` keys. You lose saved views, but not cutomized templates created with `Apply to Folders`. Intelligent use of that can mitigate the annoyance of resetting your preferred views.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head as usual "Great Job!". The powershell script returned 5000. I researched your suggestion and created a detailed document of the steps (as I usually do) so if I have to do this again I have the steps ready to use.

In the windows registry I plan on performing the following:
1. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
2. Export this registry to save a copy before deleting.
3. Delete the BagMRU and Bags keys.

I googled "Is it safe to delete BagMRU?" Found that Windows will automatically rebuild the "BagMRU" and "Bag" keys after a restart.

Comment: I was thinking of culling these couple comments for an edit/update to my answer, but it might be seen by more if you add a follow-up/final resolution post script to your question...

Comment: I was hoping to consider this problem final but when I ran that powershell script to view the number of saved views it still returned 5000 as before deleting the "BagMRU" and "Bag" keys. Am I not understanding or missing something?

Comment: No, did you happen to check after deletion? I'm guessing that a sync setting or 3rd-party utility restored them...

Comment: After deletion, the keys will be recreated and *gradually* grow as you use **Explorer** and the common dialogs...

Comment: I did not check the number of saved views immediately after deleting the "BagMRU" and "Bag" keys. I checked 5 days later. I did review the registry immediately after the delete and just before this comment and the size of the 2 registries are significantly smaller (ManyMany folders\subfolders in BagMRU to no folders and ManyMany folders\subfolders in Bags to 1 folder and 1 subfolder).  It does not look like these 2 keys have been repopulated like they were before deleting the "BagMRU" and "Bag" keys. I did make a backup of [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell] before the delete.

Comment: @mikemich: Cool. Check it periodically -- in case some schedulled task or similar either restores the old vlaues or is doing something to create new views...

Comment: I am still bothered by the saved views at 5000 so I did some research.    
(1) Ran the saved view count against: HKcu:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU.  
(2) Deleted the BagMRU and Bags keys from: HKcu:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell.   
**SHOULD HAVE I:** Deleted BagMRU and Bags keys from: HKcu:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell (which is chucked full of folders)?